# Linux - Deleting files (only) within nested directories

Tags: linux, bash

I have a set of user folders, where they can keep their PDFs. I want to create a cron job which would delete all files which are over a week old (and files only, not directories) within all the nested directories.

So, my directory structure looks as following:

```
users
│  index.html
│
+---+ a-long-string-of-random-characters-1
|   │   file1.pdf
│   │   file2.pdf
│   
|
+---+ a-long-string-of-random-characters-2
│   │   file1.pdf
│   │   file2.pdf
|
|
...
```

I already have about 8 directories. I need to delete all pdfs in the `user` directory and it's sub-direcotries.

I use the following to delete old db backups:

```
00 06 * * * find /path/to/backups/* -mtime +14 -delete
```

Some parts are quite obvious. `+14` would become `+7`, `/*` would be `/*.pdf`

```
00 06 * * * find /path/to/users/*.pdf -mtime +7 -delete
```

But what about the sub-directories?

Cheers

Comment: I don't think you understand how `find` works.

Comment: Go to [unix.se] and search for ["\[find\] delete files older than"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfind%5D+delete+files+older+than)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
00 06 * * * find /path/to/users/*.pdf -mtime +7 -delete
```

With:

```
00 06 * * * find /path/to/users/ -type f -iname '*.pdf' -mtime +7 -delete
```

Notes:

1. `find` will automatically recurse through subdirectories.  We just need to tell it to start at `/path/to/users/` and it will look through all of `users` subdirectories recursively.
2. To limit the search to regular files, we add `-type f`.
3. To limit the search to files whose name end in `.pdf`, we add `-iname '*.pdf'` *(using -iname makes the match case-insensitive, which is usually a good idea)*.
4. Before creating the above cronjob, try:

   ```
   find /path/to/users/ -type f -name '*.pdf' -mtime +7
   ```

   This will show you what files would be deleted.  If you are satisfied that this list is what you want, then you run it again with `-delete` or create the cronjob.